# Do you need to await process in Cloud Run for avoiding background activities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

We are having a Google Cloud Run instance running and we are receiving Post requests on a specific endpoint. When a request is coming in, we are publishing it to a Pubsub and firing a javascript, asynchronous function with some queries and mutations in Prisma database.

We are currently not awaiting this, but just sending a response before this function call is ready.

Now i am wondering if this is good behaviour for Google Cloud Run.

Some example code:

```
    app.post("/endpoint/example", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const data = req.query.data

        this.pubSubService.publish(data);

        return res.send(200)
      } catch (error) {
        return res.send(400)
      }
    });
```

In the pubSubService publish we are firing another async function with the db mutations / queries.

My question is:

Do we need to await this publish function, yes or no? And why?

Comment: You should probably take a look at what the [`await` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) actually does - it simply pauses the `async` function execution "until a `Promise` is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected), and to resume execution of the `async` function after fulfillment."

Comment: Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response system. When your code returns the HTTP Response, your container can be terminated, CPU idled, etc. Do not create background threads that continue execution after the HTTP response.  `After startup, you should only expect to be able to do computation within the scope of a request: a container instance does not have any CPU allocated if it is not processing a request.` https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract

Comment: So @JohnHanley, if i understand correctly, we do need to await until we send the res.send(200). So after each query / mutation / Promise is fulfilled, and than send response?

Comment: Once your code returns the HTTP response, assume your container will be stopped/terminated.

Answer (score 2):

With Cloud Run, the CPU is active only when a request is being processed. That means, if you have only one request processed at a point of the time, just after you have sent the HTTP response back to the client, the Cloud Run instance stops any process (in reality throttle close to 0 the CPU allocated)

Therefore, if you create a background process and you return immediately the response, the background process won't have CPU to perform its job.

So, perform all what you have to do, here post a message to PubSub, (a)wait the correct sending and then reply to the requester.